# Slick Carousel - revealing new slide item on smart phone ONLY

Tags: jquery, function, initialization, media-queries, slick.js

This is just a question on if it is possible.If this question has been asked before, please link it in the comments or answers.

Is it possible to hide a slide from a Slick Carousel, only to reveal it when the user is looking at the carousel from their smartphone?

Is this a built in function or something I would have to duct-tape together with media queries, reinit calls and the add/destroy functions?

Slick Carousel can be found [HERE](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) and demos [HERE](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Comment: I really don't think such an option exits , when you say mobile are you talking about below a certain `width` or `touch devices` ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik that is correct.  I kinda figured this functionality wasn't currently available. I just thought I would ask before I burn my candle at both ends.